# in_array doesn't like list of numbers stored in session

Tags: php

I'm doing the following code to ensure the next random number called hasn't been called before.

```
do {   
    $n = rand(1,19);
} while(in_array($n, $myarray));    
$thisqno = $n;
```

`$myarray` is a session of numbers as so:

> $myarray = array($_SESSION['pastqs']);

`$_SESSION['pastqs']` would equal something like: 1,4,6,12,10, etc. I don't get an error but it returns any random number between 1-19 including ones in `$myarray/$_SESSION['pastqs']`.

If I change $myarray to a hardcoded list of numbers like this:

> $myarray = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);

It works fine! So I am assuming it doesn't like my session for some reason. I am printing all my data to the page and when echo'ing the session it correctly prints the numbers I am storing...

Any ideas??

Thanks :)

Comment: What's the output if you print_r($_SESSION['pastqs']) ? I suspect $myarray = array($_SESSION['pastqs']); is not the correct way to create an array.

Answer (score 0):

If `$_SESSION['pastqs']` itself already is an array you should use

```
$myarray = isset($_SESSION['pastqs']) ? $_SESSION['pastqs'] : array();
// instead of $myarray = array($_SESSION['pastqs']);
```

What you had is something like

```
$myarray = array(
    array(1, 4, 6)
);
```

Comment: ok, so my session currently contains "0,1". I've added  $myarray = isset($_SESSION['pastqs']) ? $_SESSION['pastqs'] : array(); and then I do:  
do {   
    $n = rand(1,19);
 } while(in_array($n,$myarray)); 

but I'm now getting this error:  Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /homepages/32/....page-training.php on line 40